# Spring cloud config server fetching properties from native location is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Hi Please see the project structure of my config file
[image: Configuration server project structure]

Include these lines in the yml file

```
   spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchlocations =classpath:config/{application}
```

Here I can able to fetch properties directly under service name ,but don't know how to fetch data from folders like australia,canada .Please help

Comment: I dont think we can apply pattern for this. Its tricky ! why not create two separate config folders based on country like service-australia and service-london etc as per your case both are different config clients/applications.

Comment: In that case need to change the service name to cv-service-australia,client won't accept that

Comment: Then Australia or Canada are not config clients then add them as profiles rather than a config folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by providing another search location path in the server . see the below changes

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchlocations =classpath:config/{application},classpath:config/{application}/{label}
```

And from the client side I have to make sure that I am passing correct label.

```
spring.cloud.config.label=australia
```